# How to show explicitly there is a continuous projection if one complete metric space can isometrically embedded into another one.

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is asked in general but in particular.

I have a normed vector space $X$ and I want to show there is a projection $X'''\to X'$

My work done:

$X',X'',X'''$ are Banach spaces. And I am considering the natural monomorphisim from $X'\to X'''$ since the norm is preserved and this natural homomorphism is  onto, by norm preservation I get the boundedness of the natural homomorphism and the image is also a Banach subspace of $X'''$ so by open mapping theorem the inverse of this natural isomorphism is continuous. So it is clear that if I define a map $P:X'''\to X'$ by using the inverse of the natural isomorphism $P$ sends every element in $X'''$ onto $X'$ which is embeded isometrically into $X'''$ so if I apply P again it is also equivalent to P but I dont know how to write explicitly this $P$ projection mapping.

Answer (score 2):

The map $\Phi: X''' \to X'$ is defined by $\Phi (x''') (x)=x'''(\Theta (x))$ where $\Theta: X \to X''$ is the canonical embedding.

Comment: Thank you, and In what sense am I supposed to show  $\Phi^2=\Phi$ in preserving topology or in composition sense because in composition sense $\Phi^2=\Phi$ is not true because their domains are different. I know intuitively but it feels a bit wrong.

Comment: Let $\Phi (x''')=u'$. Consider $v'''=F(u')$ where $F: X' \to X'''$ is the canonical embedding. Then verify that $F(\Phi (v'''))=v'''$. This shows that $\Phi$ is identity on its range.  @Jale'dejaleuffnejale

Comment: thank you, besides Do you think my reasonings are needed or just giving this projection this is ok?

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale You have to give the reasoning too.